# May a male swim without a head covering?

Tags: halacha, men-male, kippa-yarmulka, swimming

Having never seen a man cover his hair with a kippah while swimming I always assumed it was permitted to do so. However I am curious if there is any halachic discussion recorded which explicitly permits a man to swim without a head covering.

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5278/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think so. The question there was in regards to tzinus, my question is in regards to the rabbinic custom which has now essentially become law for a man to cover his head at all times. I'm asking if that necessarily includes swimming

Comment: What is a "rabbinic custom"?

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is discussion, and since this is Judaism we're talking about, there is of course disagreement.

The Kof-K has a document [(PDF)](http://www.kof-k.org/articles/040408100410W-39%20Wearing%20a%20Yarmulka.pdf) regarding the wearing of the kippah, which footnotes numerous sources for the following sentence:

> Wearing a yarmulka is not necessary when a person is
>   actually in the pool, shower, or mikvah

Footnotes:

> Birchei Yosef 2:5, Sharei Teshuva 3, Ben Ish Chai ibid, Lev Ha’aretz 2:6:52, Kaf Ha’chaim 2:17, Minchas
>   Yitzchok ibid, Yabea Omer O.C. 6:15:7. Refer to Rivevos Ephraim 4:185, Shila D’kaita page 353 quoting
>   the opinion of Horav Elyashiv Shlita, Teshuvos V’hanhugos 1:12.

It also quotes several sources that are stringent. You may wish to CYLOR.